# Sorting first by text then by number on alpha numeric strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, alphanumeric

I have an array like this

```
["1","0K","11",1,"KE","PQ",5,"5"]
```

where i want it to sort first by text then by number like below

```
["KE","PQ","0K","1",1,5,"5","11"]
```

I used `local compare` but it didn't seem to be working.

```js
function desc(a,b){
  //below is the code that needs improvement
  return b.toString().localeCompare(a, undefined, {
    numeric: true,
    sensitivity: "base",
  });
}

function sort(order) {
  return order === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => desc(a, b)
    : (a, b) => -desc(a, b);
}

function stableSort(array, cmp){
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = cmp(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) return order;
    return (a[1]) - (b[1]);
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}

var arr = ["1","0K","11",1,"KE","PQ",5,"5"];
console.log(stableSort(arr, sort("asc")))
```

Comment: Why `"KE","PQ","0K"`? String comparison will give `"0K","KE","PQ"` or reverse of that.

Comment: Your OK is a Zero with Kay. 0K. Convert everything to string and use array.sort().reverse()

Comment: `i want it to sort first by text` the texts `"KE","PQ","0K"`  with zero will never sort in that order. It will be either `"0K","KE","PQ"` or reversed order of that.

Comment: How do you want to compare alphabetic ones? because using ``localeCompare`` sets ``PQ`` before ``KE``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write `filter` methods to get the `strings containing numbers`, remove the entries, get `numbers` and `strings` separately from `rest` and then sort them in the way you like.

```js
const data = ["1","0K","11",1,"KE","PQ",5,"5"];

const stringsWithNumbers = data.filter(x => /\d+[a-zA-Z]/.test(x));

const rest = data.filter(x => !stringsWithNumbers.includes(x));

const numbers = rest.filter((x) => parseInt(x, 10));
const words = rest.filter((x) => !parseInt(x, 10));

const result = [
  ...words.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)), 
  ...stringsWithNumbers.concat(numbers).sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b)),
];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wrong output.  Required output `["KE","PQ","0K","1",1,5,"5","11"]`

Comment: Required output is `["KE","PQ","0K","1",1,5,"5","11"]`

Comment: @axtck still wrong. Please check the required output mentioned in the question or in my previous comment

Comment: parseInt("0K", 10) returns 0 - it thinks it is a number. You need another way to discriminate. Why do you have a mix of strings and numbers in the input?

Comment: Your output is "1",1,5,"5" ... str,number,number,str ... ? For me your sorted array is "sorted" in a way which i would not call sorted.

Comment: @Strella look at his expected outcome

Comment: @Nitheesh updated the code, didn't realize `0` was in the string

Comment: @NidhiDadiya is this the expected outcome?

Comment: @axtck your output is correct. but how do I fit it with my code? because i want something which can do the calculations between two values a & b and provide result as 1,-1 or 0.

Comment: @NidhiDadiya what are the calculations? Could you supply an example in the question?

Comment: @axtck I mean the desc function that is calculating using local compare. i want that part to give result as 1,-1 or 0. between two values.

Comment: @axtck I managed to have that in my code. thanks a bunch.

Comment: @NidhiDadiya glad I could help!

Comment: Just an update, in the result, concat string with numbers and numbers and apply sort on that. `...stringsWithNumbers.concat(numbers).sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b))`

Comment: @NidhiDadiya I'll update the answer, could you check?

Comment: remove the numbers sort in the result. that's not needed now.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sort = (arr = []) => {
  const nonAlpha = /[^a-zA-Z]/g, nonNum = /[^0-9]/g;
  return arr.sort((a, b) => {
    const aStr = String(a), bStr = String(b);
    const aAlpha = aStr.replace(nonAlpha, ""), bAlpha = bStr.replace(nonAlpha, "");
    const alphaCompare = bAlpha.localeCompare(aAlpha);
    if(alphaCompare) return alphaCompare;
    const aNum = +aStr.replace(nonNum, ""), bNum = +bStr.replace(nonNum, "");
    return aNum - bNum;
  });
}

console.log( sort(["1","0K","11",1,"KE","PQ",5,"5"]) );
```

Comment: Incorrect output

Answer (score 1):

```
    var arr = ["1","OK","11",1,"KE","PQ",5,"5"]
    var wordArr = []
    var numArr = []
    arr.forEach((el) => {
        if(Number(el)){
            numArr.push(el)
        } else {
            wordArr.push(el)
        }
    });
    wordArr.sort()
    numArr.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    arr = wordArr.concat(numArr)
    console.log(arr)
```